# how to convert Tiff image to show the Thumbnail using C# for Exporting to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, converters, tiff, bmp

I have .tiff image which I wanted to convert in thumbnail so that I can export it to Excel file.

Which is the best image format to convert the .tiff into thumbnail using C#.

 How to compress the .tiff and Export it to Excel?.

 I am using below code but it is not effective solution.

> > `Image image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(filePath);
> >        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(image, thumbnailWidth, thumbnailHeight);`

Comment: JPEG is the best image compression.

Comment: If in doubt go for PNG. It is lossless and small and even has transparency.

Comment: Why do you need a file format to show an image?